# Apache Sling: Sling error when configuring Oracle Wallets - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/security/pki/OracleWallet

Tags: java, osgi-bundle, sling, pki, oracle-wallet

I'm trying to configure a DB Connect connection that uses Oracle Wallets, but keep running into the following error in the apache sling error log:

***PKI classes not found. To use 'connect /' functionality, oraclepki.jar must be in the classpath: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/security/pki/OracleWallet***

I've put the **osdt_cert.jar, osdt_core.jar, ojdbc6-12.1.0.1.jar and oraclepki.jar** in the **portal/lib** directory, and I've tried several entries to put the above files in the java classpath via the properties when start the sling app.
But nothing has seemed to work.

Please note I'm using **Apache Sling 6** version.

Tried with the below solution as well. But it also didn't work.
https://community.splunk.com/t5/All-Apps-and-Add-ons/Error-when-configuring-DB-Connect-3-1-4-and-Oracle-Wallets/m-p/484200

If you have any suggestions on how to resolve the above error, please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to create an OSGI bundle for **pki jar** using  **Bnd tools, Eclipse and Maven bundle plugin**.

Bnd tools gave below error when creating OSGI bundle for pki jar. And also unable to create OSGI bundle from Eclipse as well.

*oracle_wallet_bnd_tool]$ ./bnd.sh wrap ./input/oraclepki.jar
Errors
000: /data/workspace/portal/VFI/oracle_wallet/oracle_wallet_bnd_tool/./input/oraclepki.jar The default package '.' is not permitted by the Import-Package syntax.
This can be caused by compile errors in Eclipse because Eclipse creates
valid class files regardless of compile errors.
The following package(s) import from the default package null*

Have created OSGI bundle for **pki** **jar** using **Maven bundle plugin** without any error. It needs at least one dependency for pki bundle.
But when deploying the tomcat, it gives above mentioned **PKI classes not found error in apache sling log**.

We have tried to create OSGI bundle for ojdbc6 with oraclepki, osdt_cert and osdt_core dependency using Maven bundle plugin. It was also unsuccessful.